# Dashed Lines in Annotation Chart Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization, linechart

I have a requirement to show the Date & Cost series of a product per week including futures. Previously I solved this requirement previously using Google Charts Line chart and used certainty role to differentiate from past to future data. Now I got a request to show data for long term (like 5 years & future also) with date range filter like in Google Charts Annotation Chart. But I was unable to differentiate data from past to future ( previously I used to show dotted lines for future data in Google Charts Line Chart ).

I was trying to show dashed lines in Annotation Chart. I was unable to find the option of role or style in annotation chart.

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Comment: you could attach a [date range filter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#daterangefilter) to a line chart using a [dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#dashboard)

Comment: Yeah Thanks for your Comment @WhiteHat It was my last option to achieve it. But It will be very good if I have it through Annotation Chart